# How to format a number according to locale in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have wrote a unit test shown below, and it doesn't seem to do the conversion correctly, when i run the code in jsfiddle, and on this site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat
the conversion works properly.

How can i make it work in the unit test?

```js
describe("numbeformat", () => {
    const opt = new Intl.NumberFormat("de", { maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(
        123456.789
    );

    it("should render a formatted number using german locale", () => {
        expect(opt).toBe("123.456,79");
    });

    //result i'm getting is 123,456.79
});
```

Comment: How are you running the unit test?

Comment: I am running it using. npm test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are running this with Node.js and your install of Node.js does not support the selected locale.

Install the [`full-icu` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) and follow the instructions it provides.

```
npm i full-icu
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the `toLocaleString` method? Check the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Basically, you should do:

```js
const number = 123456.789;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('es-CL'));
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```